# jquery mobile wont fire pageinit or ready

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

i have 3 php pages, 1 index page and 2 other subpages which have links (sales and products) in the index page. when i click on sales, it is suppode to load sales data on `pageint` or `document ready` as am using below to debug.

```
$('[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow', function () { <-- error line
    console.log("pageshow");
});

$(document).on('pageinit', function(){ 
console.log("pageinit");
});
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log("docready");
})
```

none of the code fire when i click the link on in index page, but when the page is loaded and i refresh, i get a javascript error indicated by the error line

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'live'
```

i am using

```
jquery.1.9.1.min.js
jquery.mobile.1.3.2.min.js
```

the html of the index page is

```
<div data-role="page" data-ajax="false" id="home">
    <?php include_once("header.php");?>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="">    
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Menu</li>
            <li data-transition="flip">
                <a href="outgoing.php" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="true">sales </a>
            </li>
            <li data-transition="flip">
               <a href="settings.php" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="true">products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="../logout.php">Logout</a>
            </li>
    </ul><div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
    <?php include_once("../footer.php");?></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

what am i doing wrong?

**Edit**

I updated my code as to `$('[data-role="page"]').on('pageshow', function () {`, but non of the functions fire except i refresh the page manually after it has been full loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved the problem by setting data-ajax=false in the link that loaded the page thats not firing document readey and the rest

```
<a href="page.php" data-ajax="false">link</a>
```

thanks

Comment: All this does is loads the page without AJAX. Its not really solved anything, its just done things a different way.

Answer (score 1):

`live` is deprecated, you have to use `on` function in new version of jquery. `live` is deprecated in `1.7` and removed in `1.9`. As you are using `1.9.1` means you have to use `on`.

```
$('[data-role="page"]').on('pageshow', function ()
```

[version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: thanks, but the problems still remains. except i refresh the page, these functions won't fire

Comment: i just did, and its the same, am guessing this has to do with jqm caching pages.

Comment: for jquery mobile it is not recommended to use document ready should use the mobile related events. because the moment u enable ajax loading of pages, your document ready only load once and it will not be fired again.